# (Java) Array with file names with numbers at the end are not being sorted in numerical order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to have an array that takes all of the files in a folder and put the names in an array. The file names all have a number at the end to indicate the frame order but my code doesn't seem to be sorting it correctly.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class OsuSkinFramerDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numFrames = 0;
        int frames;
        String assetType;

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("What kind of asset is this (example: menu-back) (Please make sure you add any special characters(dashes) or else it wont work");
        assetType = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Make sure you have all of the images you want to rename in a folder. When you do, input anything");
        keyboard.nextLine();

        File directory = new File("C:\\Users\\chris\\IdeaProjects\\Osu Skin framer\\src\\TEst");
        frames = directory.list().length;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("File Count:" + frames);

        String contents[] = directory.list();

        Arrays.sort(contents);

        for(int i=0; i < contents.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(contents[i]);
        }


        while(numFrames <= frames){

                File image = new File("C:\\Users\\chris\\IdeaProjects\\Osu Skin framer\\src\\TEst\\" + contents[numFrames]);

                File rename = new File("C:\\Users\\chris\\IdeaProjects\\Osu Skin framer\\src\\TEst\\" + assetType + "-" + numFrames);

                image.renameTo(rename);

                numFrames++;
            }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the Arrays.sort() method, but when I try to sort the array I get results like

```java
1
10
100
101
...
```

As opposed to the result being

```java
1
2
3
4
...
```

How can I sort the array in numerical order?

Answer (score 1):

Your current array is of `String` type, and therefore the `Arrays.sort()` operation will sort the array lexicographically, as *text*, and not as integers.  To sort numerically, use:

```java
Arrays.sort(contents, Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::valueOf));
```